# Display value of dynamically created EditText in another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I created one mini App for learning,
When any user give any number in EditText and click on submit, then TextView & EditText created dynamically based on given Digit.

and After created new EditText, user fill Data in EditText and click on submit button...
When user click on submit data must pass in new intent and Display that data in it.
My Problem is that when I click on submit button, 
only Last EditText Value is display...

What Can I Do?
Thanks In Advance...!!!

Here is my Code...

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Digit Here" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ADD" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DELETE" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SUBMIT" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainAvtivity.java

```
package com.example.textviewdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView addTv;
    private EditText edt, edtAdd, edArray;
    private Button add, delete, submit;
    LinearLayout layout;
    List<EditText> allEds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int no = Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString());
                allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

                for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {

                    addTv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    addTv.setText("TextView " + i);
                    addTv.setId(i);
                    layout.addView(addTv);

                    edtAdd = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

                    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    allEds.add(edtAdd);
                    edtAdd.setText("Test" + i);
                    edtAdd.setId(i);
                    layout.addView(edtAdd);
                }
            }
        });
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
                String[] items = new String[allEds.size()];
                String str = String.valueOf(allEds.size());
                for (int j = 0; j < allEds.size(); j++) {
                    items[j] = allEds.get(j).getText().toString();
                    data.putExtra("edData", items[j]);
                    data.putExtra("size", str);
                    /*
                     * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[j],
                     * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     */
                }

                startActivity(data);
            }
        });
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                layout.removeAllViews();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_1" >
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Display.java

```
package com.example.textviewdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Display extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView getText;
    LinearLayout linear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        Intent get = getIntent();

        linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_1);

        int size = Integer.parseInt((get.getExtras().getString("size")));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            getText = new TextView(Display.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            getText.setText(get.getExtras().getString("edData"));
            linear.setLayoutParams(params);
            getText.setId(i);
            linear.addView(getText);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
My Problem is that when I click on submit button,
only Last EditText Value is display...
```

*Because,* you are overwriting the data in your for loop using this key:

```
for (int j = 0; j < allEds.size(); j++) {
    items[j] = allEds.get(j).getText().toString();
    data.putExtra("edData", items[j]);
    data.putExtra("size", str);
}
```

And later, retrieve using index id till j = size.

You can either use index in key or pass String array itself:

**Approach 1:**

```
data.putExtra("size", str);  //you don't need to keep this in loop as its same.
for (int j = 0; j < allEds.size(); j++) {
    items[j] = allEds.get(j).getText().toString();
    data.putExtra("edData"+j, items[j]);
}
```

and

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("size"));
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("edData"+j);
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Pass String array in intent, and later, retrieve it in second activity:

```
intent.putExtra("strings", myStringArray);
```

and

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below you are updating the value every time that's why it is only showing last digit.

```
package com.example.textviewdemo;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private TextView addTv;
        private EditText edt, edtAdd, edArray;
        private Button add, delete, submit;
        LinearLayout layout;
        List<EditText> allEds;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

            layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);

            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int no = Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString());
                    allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {

                        addTv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
                        addTv.setText("TextView " + i);
                        addTv.setId(i);
                        layout.addView(addTv);

                        edtAdd = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

                        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
                        allEds.add(edtAdd);
                        edtAdd.setText("Test" + i);
                        edtAdd.setId(i);
                        layout.addView(edtAdd);
                    }
                }
            });
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent data = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
                    String[] items = new String[allEds.size()];
                    String str = String.valueOf(allEds.size());
                    for (int j = 0; j < allEds.size(); j++) {
                        items[j] = allEds.get(j).getText().toString();
                        /*
                         * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[j],
                         * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         */
                    }
                    //changes made here
                        data.putExtra("edData", items);
                        data.putExtra("size", str);

                    startActivity(data);
                }
            });
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    layout.removeAllViews();

                }
            });
        }
    }



package com.example.textviewdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Display extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView getText;
    LinearLayout linear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        Intent get = getIntent();

        linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_1);

        int size = Integer.parseInt((get.getExtras().getString("size")));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            getText = new TextView(Display.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            String[] data = get.getExtras().getString("edData");
            String textOnRequest = ";
            for(int i=0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
                textOnResponse += data[i];
            }
            getText.setText(textOnResponse);
            linear.setLayoutParams(params);
            getText.setId(i);
            linear.addView(getText);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `data.putExtra("edData", items[j]);` will simply put the last array item in intent as extra. Or am I missing something?

Comment: just look again you need to provide a array of Strings and fetch their value in your activity as array of String.

Comment: I know that. I was just pointing out your mistake so u can improve answer :)

Comment: In this  data.putExtra("edData", items[j]); j is not accessible out side of scope. when i declare int j; and run program . after click on submit App is crased..

Comment: you have to pass array instead of single string just look the code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to store values,
And later on you can retrieve from shared preferences.

**Write to Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

**Read from Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Check in Google API [Shared - Preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference)

Answer (score -1):

Move `data.putExtra` for both `size` and `edData` keys outside `for` loop `data.putExtra` work like a Map which have a unique keys

```
// Prepare items Array 
for (int j = 0; j < allEds.size(); j++) {
    items[j] = allEds.get(j).getText().toString();
}
data.putExtra("edData", items);
data.putExtra("size", str);
```

Now get `edData` as String Array instead of String from `Bundle`.

Comment: `data.putExtra("edData", items[j]);` will simply put the last array item in intent as extra. Or am I missing something? and use of `int j` after loop. that's gonna give compile time error in first place.